# Wordpress - registering a script depending on JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I register and enqueue my script like this:

```
wp_register_script('api_script', plugins_url('api.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('api_script');
```

My api.js file consist only of a call to the `$.ajax` function :

```
$.ajax({
    /*Stuff*/
});
```

However, I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: $ is undefined`.
Help please!

Comment: You have to wait for jQuery before start your function : `(function($){ // your stuff })(jQuery);`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure about the syntax. How do I call the ajax function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing javascript with jQuery for Wordpress you want to write "safe" jQuery functions by not using the dollar sign. You can use:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   /*Stuff*/
});
```

Or you can pass a dollar sign as a parameter like this:

```
(function($) {
   $.ajax({
      /*Stuff*/
   });
 })(jQuery);
```

And it then runs an anonymous function with a parameter passing the jQuery object.